# Google Search Console - Scan Request does not work

Tags: google, google-search-console, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, search

I have a problem with Google's Search Console.

When I "Fetch as Google" and status is Complete, I click on "Request Indexing", fill in the Captcha and Submit.

Nothing happens after i click on Submit, i see a loading circle for a split second and then I still have the submit window as if I didn't fill it.

Why this?
Thank You in advance

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache in your browser, or using another browser?

Comment: Thank you @dan♦ for your answer. Yep tried both cache clearing and other browser (Opera and Firefox). Nothing happened.

Comment: Does the Captcha have a green arrow like [this](https://www.rebelytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Screen-Shot-2016-11-19-at-09.25.43.png)? Do you have any `noindex` directives in your meta tags or server header - or is there a _disallow_ directive in your _robots.txt_ for that URL(s)? Lastly, what does it say under `Search Console > Google Index > Index Status`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be forgetting to click a radio button for "Crawl only this URL" or "Crawl this URL and its direct links".   You need to select one of those two options before the "Go" button works:

[image]

Once you click the "Go" button, then the dialog disappears and "Indexing requested" appears in the "Status" column where  the "Request indexing" button used to be:

[image]

If it still doesn't work for you, I'd suggest trying different browsers: Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Edge.  Whichever alternates you have available.